# Print variable defined as dicts in PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex, pulp

I am new to using PuLP in python and I would like to know how I can select a specific variable from my model to print and export to Excel.

I have been guided by some examples where they define the variables with indexes such as LpVariable.dicts, but when I open it in the console, the values for solving the problem do not appear. Only 0:LpVariable appears; 1:LpVariable...

This is how i defined it.
`x_var = LpVariable.dicts('x', (set_M, set_N), 0, 1, cat="Binary")`

I tried variable.value and variable.varvalue but neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to be a lot happier if you go the 1 extra step of making the x-product sets (or lists) separately and handing them over to that construction.  When you hand over the tuple of `(set_M, set_N)`, pulp's indexing is a bit weird.  Just make a separate index set for the cross product (where needed) using either a comprehension or one of the `itertools` methods.

Also, you don't need to put the bounds in for `Binary`.  It is implied.

This leads to much easier indexing when you want to access the variables in the model:

```
from pulp import *

M = {1, 2, 3, 4}
N = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}

# some example x-products.  Itertools could also be used, but comprehensions are a snap:
MN = {(m, n) for m in M for n in N}
MN_lite = {(m, n) for m in M for n in N if m < 3}


prob = LpProblem('sample', LpMinimize)

# VARS
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', indices=MN, cat="Binary")
y = LpVariable.dicts('y', indices=MN_lite, cat="Integer")
z = LpVariable.dicts('z', indices=N)

# sample print / access...  No value yet
print(x[2, 'C'].varValue)  # <---- this is how you want to access them!


# some silly constraints...

for n in N:
    prob += lpSum(x[m, n] for m in M) >= 2  # must pick 2 for each n in N

for n in N:
    prob += z[n] >= 4.2

# objective:  Minimize picks

prob += lpSum(x[m, n] for (m, n) in MN) + lpSum(z[n] for n in N)

prob.solve()

for m, n in sorted(MN):       # sorting, if desired
    print(f'for index {m}, {n} set: {x[m, n].varValue : 0.0f}')

for n in N:
    print(n, z[n].varValue)   # simple
```

##### Output (minus the solve data, which you should always check):

```
for index 1, A set:  1
for index 1, B set:  1
for index 1, C set:  1
for index 1, D set:  1
for index 2, A set:  1
for index 2, B set:  1
for index 2, C set:  1
for index 2, D set:  1
for index 3, A set:  0
for index 3, B set:  0
for index 3, C set:  0
for index 3, D set:  0
for index 4, A set:  0
for index 4, B set:  0
for index 4, C set:  0
for index 4, D set:  0
C 4.2
B 4.2
A 4.2
D 4.2
```

Comment: Thank you!
Just a question, if the variable x is a vector or a list, how can I print it all?
That is, not just a specific position.

Comment: There are a multitude of ways...  see the edits.  The basis is to just re-use the index set that you made the variable with, iterate over it, and pluck out the values.  If your model has a bunch of binary variables, sometimes it is clearer to filter out the zeros (not shown)